# jQuery multiselect plugin dropdown opening after body

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

So I have this dashboard that I use for one of my apps, and there one of the pages have a jQuery plugin `ui-multiselect-menu` (common one), which pops out under the input when you click it.

That should be the case, but when I click the input for dropdown it throws me down right after the entire body and shows `ui-multiselect-menu` there... I tried everything basically but can't figure it out.

The jQuery throws the

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined"

Within the original jQuery file, that might be the problem, but not sure how to solve it.

Any idea what might break the `ui-multiselect-menu` and sending it right below the body?